# boost: text_file_backend file_name and collector target

Tags: c++, logging, boost, boost-log, log-rotation

When `text_file_backend` is set used and `collector` is set, are log files created in `keywords::target` directory or does `collector` move old log files there?

If `collector` moves them, when does `collector` do it, immediately after old log file is closed and new is created or in some other moment?

Again, if `collector` moves them at some moment, new log file (or files) is in one place and old log files are in another place. Assuming that I want `collector` to delete very old files, is there a way to leave log files in the same place where they were created but delete very old files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior is rather well documented [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/sink_backends.html#log.detailed.sink_backends.text_file).

In essence, the sink writes a log file which name is specified in the `file_name` named parameter. If this parameter is a string template, the file name is re-generated every time a new file is opened.

At certain conditions, the sink may rotate the file. This means that the current file is closed and passed to the collector, if one is set. Then a new file is opened.

The collector does the file management. Upon being passed a new file, it may perform limit checks on the older files and the filesystem in the *storage* - the directory you provide in the `target` named parameter. At this point older files may get deleted from the storage in order to fulfill the limits and be able to put the new file there as well.

It is possible to specify the storage directory in the `target` parameter to be the same as the one where you write the original file (the directory from the `file_name` parameter). In this case certain limits may be less reliably maintained (e.g. total file size will not include the file that is currently being written, so older files will still be deleted only upon rotation), but other than that it should still work as described.

Comment: You just assured me that it's OK to have collector target same as original log files directory. That's what I needed in the end. Also, it's pleasure to get answer from author of library I asked about. Thanks!